# Flat epimorphism of rings that is not finitely presented?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

There is a result from E.G.A. that a morphism of rings $\varphi: A\to B$ induces an open immersion $f:\operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec}A$ if and only if all three of the following conditions hold:

- $\varphi$ is an epimorphism
- $\varphi$ is flat
- $\varphi$ is of finite presentation

Is there a canonical example of a morphism of rings that satisfies the first two conditions but not the third?

In general, how does the induced map fail to be an open immersion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is a multiplicative subset of $A$, the canonical morphism;
\begin{align*}
\varphi\colon A&\longrightarrow S^{-1}A\\
x&\longmapsto \frac x1
\end{align*}
is a flat epimorphism.
(This is an example which shows that, in the category of commutative rings, ‘epimorphism’ does not mean ‘surjective’.)

Comment: Thanks, I was just thinking about $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$.  Do you know if such a morphism has to be injective on spectra?

Comment: Hmmm… Not sure (I don't have a book at hand), but it might be at least a monomorphism, from the categorical point of view (is it the same as injective?). If you can read French, you might be interested by some papers from [Pierre Samuel's seminar](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?id=SAC_1967-1968__2_) in the 60's.

Comment: Of course, for the example with $S^{-1}A$, it is standard it is injective on spectra. I meant I'm not sure for general flat epimorphisms.

Comment: It seems that [any epimorphism is injective on spectra](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VW).